# How do I implement generics <E> in a linked List?

Tags: java, generics, linked-list

I have been trying to create a linked list that uses generics to return a data type of the user's choosing. The problem is that my method `public E get(int sub)`
is not recognizing my `return cursor.contents` as a type `E generic`.

```
public E get(int sub)
{
    Node cursor = head; //start at the beginning of linked list. 

    for (int c = 1; c <= sub; c++)
    {
        cursor = cursor.next; //move forward by one. 
    }

    return cursor.contents;//return the element that the cursor landed on. 
}


 public class Node <E>
{
        public E contents; 
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public Node next = null; //points to the next node
    //a method has no return type and has the same name as the class
    public Node(E element)
    {
        this.contents = element; 
    }
}
```

as I have shown above the contents parameter is declared as `type E` in the Node, but the get method will not recognize `cursor.contents` as a proper return type.

The system recomments that I either change the return type to `Object`, which is not an option. Or I change contents to a type `E` which has already been done, but it still gives me a compilation error.

Comment: Isn't the get method located in the Node class?

Comment: I added the generics to the node cursor to make it node<E> cursor, but now when I test it with the code below it gives me a new error and I cant figure out why my code wont return the proper output.

Comment: public class Demo1
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  MyLinkedList<String> t = new MyLinkedList<String>();
  t.add("Thousand Oaks"); 
  for (int x = 0; x < t.size(); x++)
  {
   System.out.println(t.get(x));
  }
 
  t.add("Hollywood");
 
  for (int x = 0; x < t.size(); x++)
  {
   System.out.println(t.get(x));
  }
 
  for (int x = 0; x < 500; x++)
  {
   t.add("Junk data " + x);
  }
 
  System.out.println(t.get(64));
  System.out.println(t.get(499));
  System.out.println(t.get(319));

  System.out.println("--------");
  System.out.println("Cool!  I didn't crash!");
 }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you need to change it to:

```
public E get(int sub)
{
    Node<E> cursor = head; //you forgot the generics here

    for (int c = 1; c <= sub; c++)
    {
        cursor = cursor.next; 
    }

    return cursor.contents;
}


 public class Node <E>
{
    public E contents; 
    public Node<E> next = null; //you also even suppressed the raw type here

    public Node(E element)
    {
        this.contents = element; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain where the OP went wrong instead of just providing a copy-pasteable answer

Comment: There could be more ;) I think it's interesting to note how and why the original return type disagreed with the declared return type.

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting the generic type on the declaration of your `Node cursor` variable.  What happens when you change that to `Node<E> cursor`.

Also, you're not providing context of the linked list class itself - that's where the generic `<E>` should be declared.

Comment: True, seems like either solution would work! If the first solution is used, however, Node should be a static class. Otherwise the `<E>` from the LinkedList class can be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your method

```
public E get(int sub)
```

You initialize a cursor as a Node instead of `Node<E>`.

```
Node cursor = head; //start at the beginning of linked list.
```

This will cause the element type to be Object which is what you get when you write

```
return cursor.contents;
```

To Solve:

Either use a `Node<E>` or explicitly cast the return to `E`

Answer (score 0):

Are these part of a class with a typed parameter, such as `MyLinkedList<E>`? The problem may be that you added a `<E>` type parameter to the Node class as well, which may refer to a different class `E` that is not necessarily the same `E` referenced by the outer class. Try changing `Node <E>` to `Node`.and see if it works.